# Property [detalle] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hola buenas tardes a todos, tengo el siguiente dilema: tengo 2 tablas que se relacionan entre si (transferencia bodega y det_transferencia_bodega) las relaciones en los modelos las tengo asi:

Modelo TransferenciaBodega ( relacion 1 a muchos, una transferencia puede tener muchos detalles)

```
 public function det_transferencia_bodegas(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\DetTransferenciaBodega','transferencia_bodega_id','id');
}
```

Modelo DetTransferenciaBodega (un detalle de pertenece a solo una transferencia)

```
 public function transferencia_bodegas(){
   // return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\TransferenciaBodega', 'transferencia_bodega_id');
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\TransferenciaBodega','transferencia_bodega_id','id');
}
```

y en mi controlador tengo una funcion SHOW para mostrar datos de ambas tablas:

```
 public function show($id){

        $transferencia = TransferenciaBodega::find($id)->first();

        return view("bodega.logistica.showTraspaso", compact("transferencia"));
```

Cuando quiero mostrar un campo del detalle en mi vista blade

```
({{$transferencia->det_transferencia_bodegas->detalle}})
```

me muestra el error:

> Property [detalle] does not exist on this collection instance.

Me queda la duda si estoy aplicando bien las relaciones, segun lo que lei y entendi de la documentacion estaria correcto pero no se si sera asi...

Comment: ¿Entonces quieres mostrar a `TransferenciaBodega` junto con todos sus detalles?

Comment: exacto, necesito mostrar en la vista datos de ambas tablas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que recibes es por que estás tratando de acceder a una propiedad que en esa entidad no existe, pues pertenece a otra, dado lo que expones en los comentarios, entonces tu consulta debe estar de esta forma:

```
$transferencia = TransferenciaBodega::with('det_transferencia_bodegas')->findOrFail($id);
```

Es decir cargas todos los *detalles de transferencia de bodega* asociados a un modelo de `TransferenciaBodega`, el cual filtras por medio de su `id`.

Recomiendo trabajes en ese caso con `findOrFail` para que en caso de que no se encuentre algún modelo asociado al id indicado entonces recibas como respuesta una excepción.

Entonces esta consulta te debería estar retornando:

- Un objeto con los datos de la *TransferenciaBodega*
- Una colección con todos los *det_transferencia_bodegas*

**Referencias**

- [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)
- [eloquent not found exceptions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#not-found-exceptions)

Comment: consegui mostrar datos pero me asalta otra duda...antes para mostrar datos en una tabla con un foreach lo podia hacer, pero de esta manera no me resulta, la logica seria utilizar foreach aun?

Comment: Basandome en lo que menciono en la misma respuesta el foreach solo lo vas a ocupar para iterar los objetos de la colección de `det_transferencia_bodegas` pues de `TransferenciaBodega` solo estas obteniendo un objeto por tanto ahi no aplica un foreach

Comment: claro, por ejemplo para mostrar un dato de det_transferencia_bodegas lo puedo mostrar asi:  {{$transferencia->det_transferencia_bodegas[0]->materiales->detalle}}, pero en el foreach no me funciona

Comment: No alcanza con que digas que no funciona, por favor edita tu pregunta muestra como lo estas intentado a nivel de código y el error o comportamiento que estás obteniendo

Comment: si mis disculpas, el foreach lo tengo asi:   foreach ($det_transferencia_bodegas as $det)
                    <tr>

                    <td>{{$det->cantidad}}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach y el error que me arroja es: ErrorException
Undefined variable: det_transferencia_bodegas

Comment: Toda aclaración debe ir en la pregunta